# "undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e6ec28>:0x4e6e3d0>" in rails 4.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e6ec28>:0x4e6e3d0>
```

I am getting this error while I am going to create a comment associated with the posts.

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Above is the section of the form where i am getting the error..

My code in comments controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find (params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comments].permit(:commenter, :body))
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Please point out where I am wrong. I am a newbie to ruby on rails.

my routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts 
  resources :comments
  root to:"welcome#index"
  get "welcome/index"
```

my rake routes:

```
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)             posts#index
              POST   /posts(.:format)             posts#create
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)         posts#new
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)    posts#edit
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#show
              PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#update
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#update
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#destroy
     comments GET    /comments(.:format)          comments#index
              POST   /comments(.:format)          comments#create
  new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
 edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
      comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
              PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
              PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
              DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
```

My edited routes.rb ::

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :post  do
    resources :comments
  end
  root to:"welcome#index"
  get "welcome/index"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), but you didn't define it in `routes.rb`. You should have:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

And this should work.

Comment: if i do this then my server is not getting started.. saying 

"syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)"

Comment: @user3322822 you must have broken something. Please show your routes.rb again.
PS make sure you have `end` on the end of `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Probably removed the `Blog::Application.routes.draw do` or similar

Comment: my routes.rb::
// 
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

    resources :post  do
    resources :comments
  root to:"welcome#index"
   get "welcome/index"

 end
//

Comment: @user3322822 you forgot `end` after `resources :comments`. Please copy/paste carefully.
And BTW, I think you should learn some Ruby basics...

Comment: @Marek :: now my server is starting but one more problem:: i am getting the below error ::

No route matches [GET] "/posts"

sorry if i behaving like a dumb.. i am new to ruby..

Comment: @user3322822 again: Please copy/paste carefully. In my snippet, there's `resources :posts`, but you have `resources :post` in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @Marek Lipka :: thanks a lot.. now its working.. i will get back to you.. if any thing goes wrong..thanx again..

Comment: @user3322822 well. Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: yea sure...@MarekLipka